# Mirroring on-premise database to Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server

Can we establish a mirroring between on-premise database to Azure SQL Database?
Please do let me know?

Regards,

Naveen J V

Answer (score 0):

How often do you need the database to be mirrored? Do you need this for HA/DR capabilities? Or do you just want to take some of the load off the on-premise database?

Read these articles: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/stretch-database/stretch-database

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3630/connect-an-azure-sql-database-to-an-onpremises-sql-server/

https://www..slideshare.net/jamserra/hadr-options-with-sql-server-in-azure-and-hybrid